# How to get access to TopologyContext within an abstract class

Tags: java, redis, apache-storm, jedis

My goal is to add metrics throughout the topology. Things work well on bolts that extend Base/Rich bolt classes, but I fail to register any metrics within a bolt that extends the following `AbstractRedisBolt` [class](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/external/storm-redis/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/redis/bolt/AbstractRedisBolt.java).

I am trying to get the TopologyContext within a bolt that extends the `AbstractRedisBolt`. However, the `prepare` method of this class does not expose the topology context to derived classes.

I tried to extend the `AbstractRedisBolt` class by defining a class property for the context + a method to return that property, however that didn't really work out. I end up getting the reference to topology context within my bolt, however the `context.registerMetric` operation doesn't register any metrics.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just overwrite `prepare()` including a call to super class:

```java
public class MyRedisBolt extends AbstractRedisBolt {
    private TopologyContext context = null;

    public void prepare(Map map, TopologyContext topologyContext, OutputCollector collector) {
        super.prepare(map, topologyContext, collector);
        this.context = topologContext;
    }
}
```